# sqlite: How to add a counter to an existing table

Tags: sqlite, counter

This is an sqlite specific question. I have a table x0 and would like to add a counter:

```
ALTER TABLE x0 ADD counter INTEGER;
UPDATE x0 SET counter = ?
```

With ? something like: @counter := @counter +1.

Any idea?

Edit 1:
I found an easy solution but not very flexible:

```
UPDATE x0 SET counter = ROWID;
```

But this is not very flexible. For example, if I want to count within groups like in this example with MySQL: [count within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055644/mysql-counter-within-group).

Comment: In which order should the rows be counted?

Comment: Order plays no rule. The idea is to add an identification number.

Comment: So you don't actually need a counter, but just a unique value?

Comment: Yes! I asked for the counter since a possible solution for this simple example may be more flexible if for example I want to count within groups (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055644/mysql-counter-within-group)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tables already have a unique identifier, in the form of the [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), so you could just replace `?` with `rowid`.

If you want to have consecutive values, or restarting counting within some group, you have to manually count how many other rows are before each row:

```
UPDATE x0
SET counter = (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM x0 AS x02
               WHERE x02.rowid <= x0.rowid
               -- AND x02.group_value = x0.group_value
              );
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about rowid until I asked my question.